# How can I filter out global table sync data from dynamodb stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using dynamodb global table (version 2019). And I also attached a lambda as the stream listener for any data change happened on the dynamodb table.

When setup all of these, I found the lambda is triggered by both local region update and global table sync. Is there a way to identify whether a stream event is from global table sync in the lambda?

I know when using global table 2017, there is an extra field `aws:rep:updateregion` added on every item in the table. This field tells whether the change is made by which region.

But I am using version 2019 (because I can't use 2017 on a table with existing data), there is no such field. How can I identify the region from the stream events?

Comment: You shouldn't need that field as DynamoDB Streams for global tables version 2019.11.21 should only publish 1 record (instead of 2) for each write - **are you sure you're getting 2 records for 1 item update**? This is why the field was removed.

Answer (score 0):

With GTv2 the design pattern is to provide your own `SourceRegion` attribute during the write and then you can event filter by it with the Lambda running in each region so it only processes local writes.